# Working with nls function produces a singular gradient

Tags: r, nls

I want to fit a nonlinear least-squares model to my data using the `nls` function, but I get an error:

My data are:

```
y=c(0.3,1.5,4.1,10.1,21.9,39,4,58.2,77,89.6,95,98.3,100)

x=c(30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90)
```

I have used the following R command:

```
fit<-nls(y~a/(1+exp(-b*(x-c))), start=list(a=1,b=0.5,c=25))
```

It seems that something went wrong in start, but not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are several approaches:

**1) nls** Better starting values are needed.  First take the reciprocal of both sides and use the `"plinear"` algorithm which does not require starting values for linear parameters, in this case `a`.  Then use that as starting values for your fit.

```
fit0 <- nls(1/y ~ 1 + exp(-b*(x-c)), start = list(b = .5, c = 25), alg = "plinear")
fit <- nls(y~1/(1+exp(-b*(x-c))),start=coef(fit0)[1:2], alg = "plinear")

plot(y ~ x)
lines(fitted(fit) ~ x)
fit
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ 1/(1 + exp(-b * (x - c)))
   data: parent.frame()
       b        c     .lin 
  0.1355  64.9761 106.7095 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1516

Number of iterations to convergence: 13 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 6.85e-06
```

[image: screenshot]

**2) nls/SSlogis** R provides the `SSlogis` self starting model.  No starting values are needed.  Note that it is parameterized such that b = 1/B.

```
nls(y ~ SSlogis(x, a, c, B))
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ SSlogis(x, a, c, B)
   data: parent.frame()
     a      c      B 
106.71  64.98   7.38 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1516

Number of iterations to convergence: 2 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 4.087e-06
```

**3) drc** The drc package can also fit this and provides its own starting values.  The parameter names are different with b, d and e below corresponding to -b, a and c in the question.

```
library(drc)

fm <- drm(y ~ x, fct = L.3())
plot(fm)
fm
```

giving:

```
A 'drc' model.

Call:
drm(formula = y ~ x, fct = L.3())

Coefficients:
b:(Intercept)  d:(Intercept)  e:(Intercept)  
      -0.1355       106.7093        64.9761
```